# react-native custom fetch polyfill

Tags: javascript, react-native, timeout, fetch, abort

Is it possible to have my own fetch polyfill in react-native without forking react-native and without explicitly import the polyfill in each module?

The purpose of it is have my own fetch polyfill that supports timeout to handle weak internet connections and avoid memory leak.

This fork has timeout feature:

https://github.com/benestudio/fetch/tree/feature/timeout

`npm install whatwg-fetch-timeout --save`

Comment: I am looking for a similar solution. This is the best I could find for react-native: https://github.com/robinpowered/react-native-fetch-polyfill

Comment: @vijayst I can propose an other implementation:

https://github.com/benestudio/fetch/tree/feature/timeout

`npm install whatwg-fetch-timeout --save `

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2556

Comment: I tried both: whatwg-fetch-timeout and react-native-fetch-polyfill. Timeout is being set on xhr but the timeout callback is not getting triggered. Both does not work for me in react-native.